# Subselecting R XTS object by time causing duplicate rows

Tags: r, xts

I have an XTS object that I am subselecting by time but getting an incorrect result.  I am looking for the time between 2AM and 4PM, but the subselect is duplicating rows as well as not grabbing the correct times.  Here is a link to the sample data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2nxylGXOp81QTZMajdqT1MtNWM/view?usp=sharing

And here is code which illustrates the problem:

```
library(xts)
Sys.setenv('TZ'='America/Chicago')
SampleData <- readRDS('SampleData.rds')
CutSampleData <- SampleData['T02:00/T16:00']

head(CutSampleData)   ## shows it did not subselect out the correct range 
any(duplicated(as.character(index(CutSampleData))))  ## shows there are duplicated rows

CutSampleData["2016-03-11 15:02:00"]  ## here is a duplicated row.  What is going on?
```

EDIT:
Looks like the issue may be related to Linux vs Windows or some other versioning issue.  It works **correctly** on the box with this sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RMySQL_0.10.9 DBI_0.5-1     Quandl_2.8.0  xts_0.9-7     zoo_1.7-13   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.2.1      R6_2.1.3        tools_3.3.1     grid_3.3.1      jsonlite_1.0    lattice_0.20-33
```

But does not work with this sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 14393)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Any ideas why this is breaking on windows ?  Does it have to do with how XTS deals with POSIXct times?

Comment: Please post a reproducible sample that you can copy paste from the text of your post

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to grab the data sample from the link.  Just download it and put it in your R working directory and then you will be able to copy paste and see the issue.

Comment: I cannot replicate any of this.  `head(CutSampleData)` shows the first index value is "2016-03-10 02:00:00", which is what is expected.  And `anyDuplicated(index(CutSampleData))` shows there are no duplicates.  Please add the actual output you see to your question (instead of a comment that says the output is wrong).  Also add the output from `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: In my R Console, head(CutSampleData) shows the first index value as  "2016-03-10 00:00:00", as if the subselect did not work.  Maybe my version of R needs to be updated?  Here is my sessionInfo:

Comment: R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xts_0.9-7  zoo_1.7-13

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.2.2      lattice_0.20-33
>

Comment: I just did the same test on a linux box and it seems to work correctly.  Is this a windows issue?  Here is the sessionInfo where it works correctly:

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C  attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

Comment: That's very difficult to read. Please edit it into your question.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich  Done, edited the main comment.  Thanks a lot for your help!